# Zend Framework - multiple modules, one layout

Tags: zend-framework, module, zend-layout

I have a Zend application with the following structure:

```
application
    configs
        application.ini
    modules
        api
            controllers
            Bootstrap.php
        default
            controllers
                IndexController.php
            models
            views
                scripts
                    index
                        index.phtml
                layouts
                    layout.phtml
            Bootstrap.php
```

My application/configs/application.ini looks like this:

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_SQLITE"
resources.db.params.dbname = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/db/test.sqlite3"

resources.modules = ""

resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/default/views/layout/"
```

My problem is that I cannot use the layout no matter what I do.
If I go to http://test.app/index/index, I can see the output of the view script, but not the layout.

Comment: Really I would have thought you'd get an error without the layout. If you change the layout path to something invalid, do you get an error then? Do you have any init methods in your main application bootstrap, or anything layout related anywhere else?

Comment: @TimFountain no you don't get an error without layout. Plus I think the problem with above is he forgot to initialize his layout (as you added in bootstrap or wherever required). Although you do get error when you have invalid path so if he's not getting any error path should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I see you specify the layout path but never the actual layout file to use.  Assuming the layout is named `layout.phtml` add this to the app's ini.

```
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
```

You can override on a per action/controller level if you ever need to use more than one layout.  In the controller you can reach the layout via `$this->_helper->layout()`
Then you have methods such as: `setLayoutPath()`, `setLayout()`, `disableLayout()`

Reference: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.layout.usage.html

Comment: If I don't specify the actual layout file, doesn't it take a default layout.phtml?

Comment: um... try it and see?  Where is this "default layout.phtml"?  You create it?  What would the default name be?  default.phtml?  layout.phtml?  I don't like defaults and ambiguity.  Be explicit.  Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: I found the answer myself here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.layout.options.html

Quote: "layout: the layout to use. Uses the current inflector to resolve the name provided to the appropriate layout view script. By default, this value is 'layout' and resolves to 'layout.phtml'. Accessors are setLayout() and getLayout()."

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your layout file in the Bootstrap.php or application.ini to be able to use it, you haven't declared which file to use.

> In Bootstrap.php

```
function _initViewHelpers()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
}
```

And you should be good to go, if you want to have multiple layout and have different condition to use layout you should look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732778/how-to-setup-multiple-layouts-in-zend-framework-eg-public-logged-in-various-co) this is pretty cool.